# Python 3 matrix and image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a matrix rappresenation of an image where every pixel is a tuple of rgb:

[image]

[image]

Basically there are two squares:

1. (162, 201, 115)
2. (43, 39, 102)

over a black square (0, 0, 0)

The square 1 is over the square 2.

The scope of the exercise is to find all the squares in the correct order and the coordinates of up/left and down/right of the two squares.
The results should be:

1. (3 4) (4 6) of  (162, 201, 115)
2. (1 2) (3 5) of (43, 39, 102)

In order to get the square I found the way:

```
def funt(pic):
    color = []
    img = immagini.load(pic)
    for i in range(len(img)):
        for h in range(len(img[0])):
            if img[i][h] !=(0,0,0):
                    color.append([img[i][h]]) if [img[i][h]] not in color else color
    return color
```

How can I get the coordinates? I cannot use numpy!

Thanks!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation. I've created the following four functions:

- `get_pixels(img)` returns a dictionary whose values are tuples with the RGB components of the colors in `img` (excluding `(0, 0, 0)`) and the values are lists of coordinates (row and column) of the pixels that have the corresponding color.
- `bounding_box(coords)` returns the coordinates of diagonally opposed vertices of the bounding box of an image region defined through  a list of coordinates.
- `is_rectangle(coords)` returns `True` if the passed list of coordinates makes up a rectangle.
- `create_image()` returns the sample image.

```py
def get_pixels(img):
    coords = {}
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        for i in range(len(img)):
            rgb = img[i][j]
            if rgb != (0, 0, 0):
                pixels[rgb] = pixels.get(rgb, []) + [(i, j)]
    return pixels

def bounding_box(coords):
    upper = min([i for i,j in coords])
    lower = max([i for i,j in coords])
    left = min([j for i,j in coords])
    right = max([j for i,j in coords])
    return upper, lower, left, right

def is_rectangle(coords):
    upper, lower, left, right = bounding_box(coords)
    for i in range(upper, lower + 1):
        for j in range(left, right + 1):
            if (i, j) not in coords:
                return False
    return True
```

#### Demo

```py
In [382]: img = create_image()

In [383]: pixels = get_pixels(img)

In [384]: for color, coords in pixels.items(): print(color, coords)
(43, 39, 102) [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
(162, 201, 115) [(4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4)]

In [385]: colors = list(pixels.keys())

In [386]: if not is_rectangle(pixels[colors[0]]):
     ...:     colors = colors[::-1]

In [387]: colors
Out[387]: [(162, 201, 115), (43, 39, 102)]

In [388]: for n, color in enumerate(colors):
     ...:     upper, lower, left, right = bounding_box(pixels[color])
     ...:     print(f'{n}. ({left} {upper}) ({right} {lower}) of', color)
0. (3 4) (4 6) of (162, 201, 115)
1. (1 2) (3 5) of (43, 39, 102)
```